# Xamarin: Unable to upload Archive to AppStore

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Visual Studio 2019 (Windows) /
Xamarin 4.7.0.968

I create an iOS Archive (with no errors) but when I choose Distribute / AppStore and select the ID/Profile that I have already set up in Visual Studio, I get prompted for ID/Password as expected.  But then it fails with the error:

```
AppStore bundle validation failed for archive MyApp.Mobile.iOS
"altool" exited with code 1.
```

Does anyone have any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: Are you using Google libraries in your project. Check the solution in [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/413403/#Comment_413403) may help.

Comment: Could you verify that you increased "Build Version" in info.plist?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, the upload from VS doesn't give you proper message why the upload fails. In order to debug it, you need to upload it "manually". The steps are:

1. Build your project in `Release` configuration
2. Right click on the iOS project and select `Show IPA file on Build Server`
3. A `Finder` window will open on the **Mac** with the `ipa` file being preselected.
4. Copy the file to some location that you can access easily (e.g. your Dekstop)
5. Open the `Terminal`
6. Write the following command: `xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios --file "path/to/application.ipa" --username "YOUR_ITMC_USER" --password "YOUR_ITMC_PASSWORD"`

If your application is on the Desktop, the path will look like this: `~/Desktop/application.ipa`, where `application.ipa` is your app's name. Of course, you have to provide your credentials instead of `YOUR_ITMC_USER` & `YOUR_ITMC_PASSWORD` .

When you have run this command, wait a minute or two. After a while the tool will tell you if the upload fails and if so - why exactly.

P.S. You can also use the GUI [Transporter](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10152019a) app, but I don't know how much more information it may give you.

Comment: Thanks again - late here - will try tomorrow.

Comment: The Show IPA file on Build Server is greyed.  I am connected to the MAC and did a Release build.

Comment: I tried a few things I found on the Net, but the option remain greyed.  So I copied it over from the PC's bin folder and ran the xrun command you suggested.  The error is:  An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.

Comment: The option is disabled because you need to first: 1) Connect to the mac; 2) Change the configuration to Release; 3) Build the project. After you have successfully built the project, the option will "unlock".

Comment: I have tried many things.  However, copying the IPA file from my PC to the MAC and running the command you gave did help.  We can now upload it from VS and now just have to deal with any errors that are e-mailed to us.  Thanks to you though we are making progress.

Comment: For some reason Show IPA file on Build Server is now enabled?!?!  Still investigating

Comment: @RobL Do you have in your csproj file `<BuildIpa>true</BuildIpa>`? You can configure this from VS for Windows if you go to `iOS project Properties --> iOS IPA Options --> Build iTunes Package Archive (IPA)` and check the box.

Comment: Currently suffering from this error:  ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability.

Comment: Follow the steps here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/

Comment: August and this is still an issue. Microsoft dropped the ball here

Comment: For me the `Show IPA file on Build Server` is missing. Is this only available for special cases?

Comment: Attempting to upload the .ipa file through the Mac Transporter app did the trick. Turns out the problem was simply that I had already uploaded a build with the same version number. Would be great if VS could just tell me that!

Answer (score 36):

Uploading to the App Store didn't worked for me following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=windows#build-and-submit-your-app) and using Visual Studio 2019 (16.7.1). I always got

> Errors
> App Store bundle validation failed for archive XXX
> "altool" exited with code 1
> We are unable to create an authentication session.

[Apple mentions](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036) three ways for uploading:

- Xcode
- altool
- Transporter app

The easiest way is to use Xcode. When you have build for Release and archived your application (in VS 2019 on your Windows machine), you can do this on your Mac in Xcode: **Window > Organizer > Archives > Distribute App**

Comment: By far the easiest way to do this.  Thank you!

Comment: I agree. Im using this way ever since I've read this answer!

Comment: Thanks this is the answer i was looking for

Comment: Lifesaving answer.

Comment: Actually, doing it once in XCode seemed to make it work in VS on the PC?

Comment: The current version of Xamarin does not support the latest version of Xcode, and Xcode will not launch on mac if you don't have the latest version installed.  UGH

Answer (score 9):

Make sure:

1. You use App Specific Password.
2. Make sure you **INCREACE THE VERSION AND THE BUILD NUMBERS** in info.plist

Comment: Increase version code even if you haven't release the build already uploaded in the App Store.

Comment: And double check your app specific password -- I had an incorrect one saved and got this (cryptic) error message.

Answer (score 3):

I used the Transporter App because nothing else was working. The upload failed again, but Transporter actually showed a great error message... my build version number had to be updated in Info.plist (oops!).

After updating the version number and re-archiving, the Distribute button worked as intended.

### To use the Transport App

1. Download Transport App (made by Apple) from App store and open it on the mac
2. Build the iOS project in release mode on Visual Studio
3. Right-click the iOS project in Visual Studio and *Show IPA on Build Server*

   - If *Show IPA on Build Server* is greyed-out/disabled navigate to the file directly on your mac instead...

     - Open Finder
     - Click *Go > Go to Folder...* on the toolbar
     - enter *~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/*
     - Continue navigating to the release folder... *{app name}/bin/{iPhone}/Release*
     - Find the file with the .ipa extension
4. Drag the IPA file into the open *Transporter* app
5. Click *Deliver*
6. If failed, click the *Issue* button to see why

Comment: Marvelous "altool" code 1 turned into.......   ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'development' for key 'aps-environment' in 'Payload/XamarinForms.*.app/XamarinForms.*.iOS' is not supported."

ERROR ITMS-90771: "Missing Info.plist value. The Info.plist key 'BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers' must contain a list of identifiers used to submit and handle tasks when 'UIBackgroundModes' has a value of 'processing'.

Comment: Yeah for me the issue was that I had selected the wrong App Identifier in the App Store Connect.  Once I corrected that I was able to upload from Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this error was to fix my Bundle Signing settings to what Microsoft listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-app-store?tabs=vs

[image: My settings in Windows VS, but things may be a bit different between Windows VS and Mac VS]

Answer (score 0):

With the most recent VS 2019 on Windows and Xcode on Mac, Show IPA file on Build was not highlighted nor was the icon for it in the menu bar.  But when I launched VS again the both were highlighted and the folder displayed on the Mac when executed.  Perhaps there is a latency problem with VS where you need to restart it for the feature to work.

Answer (score 0):

I got this (fairly cryptic) error message when I was using an incorrect "App Specific Password".