# Getting Unable to validate archive error when Publishing to App Store in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I'm working on Publishing an iOS App to the App Store for the first time. However I get the error: `Unable to validate archive`.

As follows: `When I click " Archive for Publishing" , click " Sign and Distribute" button, select " App Store" =>" Upload" =>" Next"=>" AppStore Connect information"=>" Publish"`, it will export an ipa file, then i will get this " `Unable to validate archive` " error message

[image]

I have imported App Icon, Full Version. How to solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the uploading from VS doesn't give us more proper message why the upload fails.

But just as Apple [document](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036) mentions there are three ways for uploading:

- Xcode
- altool
- Transporter app

The easiest way is to use `Xcode`. When you have build for Release and archived your application (in VS 2019 on your Windows machine), you can do this on your Mac in Xcode: `Window` > `Organizer` > `Archives` > `Distribute App`

And there is a similar thread, you can check it here:[Xamarin: Unable to upload Archive to AppStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548047/xamarin-unable-to-upload-archive-to-appstore) .

Comment: Yes, I tried publishing through the Transporter app. Then I checked on App Store Connect it only shows up in TestFlight Tab. In the Status column I get the content: Ready to Submit Expires in 87 days. So why will 87 days be like, will it expire? I want it to be permanent. I haven't tried it on Xcode yet

Comment: You can try to use Xcode to upload.

Comment: I have dealt with the problem. Thank you very much

Comment: Using XCode as described above actually displays the error that VS for Mac did not.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when App specific password is got corrupted, or you copy paste with some spaces mistakenly, This can happen as the entered password is incorrect due to mistaken spaces included while copying.

So, at first try to copy just the App specific password (Without any spaces or new lines) and publish.

If still problem persists, then revoke the current one and generate new App Specific Password.

May this helps someone. Thanks..!